# Como guardar uma lista encadeada

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Tendo duas listas duplamente encadeadas A e B
com a estrutura

```
struct lista
    {
        Ponto* dado;        /* dado = número */
        struct lista *prox; /* ponteiro para o proximo elemento */
        struct lista *ant;  /* ponteiro para o elemento anterior */
    };
```

qual a diferente entre
1:

```
a->ant = b->ant;
a->prox = b->prox;
a->dado = b->dado;
```

e 2:

```
a = b;
```

edit 1: O porque da minha duvida:
estou fazendo um código com insertionsort com listas encadeadas. Onde o meu erro está apartir da linha onde comentei

> /* preparando para o proximo looping */

O meu objetivo apartir dessa linha é:
Lista primeiro_definitivo deve guardar o valor de Lista menor quando está no primeiro looping, porém no segundo looping Lista menor é alterado e eu não quero que primeiro_definitivo seja alterado junto, quero que ele mantenha guardando o valor que adquiriu quando entrou no if até o final do código, e não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Do jeito que está, quando Lista menor se altera posteriormente, Primeiro_definitivo acaba se alterando também.

```
Lista* lista_insertionsort(Lista* l)
{

    Lista* primeiro = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    Lista* menor = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    Lista* p = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    Lista* primeiro_definitivo = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    primeiro_definitivo = l;
    primeiro = l;
    menor = l;
    p = l;
    int alterado = 0;



    while(menor->prox != NULL)
    {
        printf("oi2\n");
        //Encontra o menor
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            if(menor->dado->x > p->dado->x)
                menor = p;
            p=p->prox;
        }
        printf("menor dado: %d", menor->dado->x);
        /*
        Nesta parte do código: menor aponta para o menor valor
        p aponta para o ultimo elemento da lista
        primeiro aponta para o primeiro que não foi alterado
        */
        //troca de posição primeiro com menor
        if(primeiro->dado->x != menor->dado->x)
        {

            if(primeiro->prox->dado->x == menor->dado->x)
                troca_adjacentes(primeiro, menor);

            else
                troca_nao_adjacentes(primeiro, menor);

            alterado = 1;
        }

        /* preparando para o proximo looping */
        if(alterado == 1){
            p = menor;
            p->ant = menor->ant;
            p->prox = menor->prox;
            p->dado = menor->dado;
            primeiro = menor->prox;
            if(menor->ant == NULL){//caso seja o menor da lista inteira, ele será o retorno
                
                primeiro_definitivo = menor;
                }
        }
        else{
        p = menor;
        primeiro = primeiro->prox;
        p->ant = primeiro->ant;
        p->prox = primeiro->prox;
        p->dado = primeiro->dado;
        }
        alterado = 0;
    }
    return primeiro_definitivo;

}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está bem confusa. Não consegui perceber qual é a sua questão / duvida. Tente explicar por palavras, e de forma bem detalhada o que está a tentar fazer e qual a sua duvida

Comment: Obrigado, adicionei mais informações

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferença é que `a` e `b` são ponteiros. Quando voce faz:

```
a->ant = b->ant;
a->prox = b->prox;
a->dado = b->dado;
```

`a` e `b` tem os mesmo valores. Mas quando você faz:

```
a = b
```

`a` e `b` são a mesma coisa (apontam pra mesma região da memoria), ou seja, tudo que mudar em `a` vai mudar em `b` e vice-versa.